# ORA-02291: integrity constraint violated - parent key not found When trying to insert null in foreign key

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I have a requirement where I have to add foreign key constraint to a certain column in the same table.
For example, I have a table PROJECT which has a primary key column "id" and another column "dependency_project_id" which is the foreign key referencing the "id" column.

I altered my table and added the constraint as below.:
ALTER TABLE PROJECT ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DEPENDENCY_PROJECT_ID FOREIGN KEY (DEPENDENCY_PROJECT_ID) REFERENCES PROJECT (ID);

However, my second requirement is, that the column "dependency_project_id" can be null in certain cases. 
But if I am trying to insert null in the dependency_project_id column, I get error "ORA-02291: integrity constraint violated - parent key not found".

Please note I am using JPA to persist my data into DB. However, if i directly insert null in dependency_project_id column in the database, i am able to do so without any issue.

Here is my entity.

> 

```
package com.oracle.estimationtool.model;
import java.util.List;
import javax.json.bind.annotation.JsonbTransient;
import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity(name = "Project")
@Table(name = "PROJECT")
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ProjectSeq", sequenceName = "PROJECT_SEQ", allocationSize = 50)
@NamedQuery(name = "Project.findProject", query = "SELECT p from Project p where p.id = :id")
public class Project extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "ProjectSeq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Integer id;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROJECT_ID")
    private  List<SolutionComponentEstimate> solutionComponentEstimates;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "CLOB NULL", name = "BUSINESS_EVENTS", nullable = true)
    @Lob
    @Basic(optional = true)
    private List<BusinessEvent>businessEvents;
    @Column(nullable = true, precision = 10, scale = 4)
    @Basic(optional = true)
    private Double duration;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROJECT_ID")
    private List<SCVersionProject> scvproject;
    @Column(name = "NAME", length = 255, nullable = false)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Size(max = 255)
    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "DEPENDENCY_PROJECT_ID", nullable = true)
    @Basic(optional = true)
    private int dependencyProjectId;
    @Column(name = "DEPENDENCY_START", nullable = true)
    @Basic(optional = true)
    private boolean dependencyStart;
    @Column(name = "DEPENDENCY_DELTA", nullable = true)
    @Basic(optional = true)
    private int dependencyDelta;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROADMAP_ID")
    @JsonbTransient
    private Roadmap roadmap;

    public Project() {
    }

    public Project(List<SolutionComponentEstimate> solutionComponentEstimates, List<BusinessEvent> businessEvents,
            Double duration, String name) {
        this.solutionComponentEstimates = solutionComponentEstimates;
        this.businessEvents = businessEvents;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<SolutionComponentEstimate> getSolutionComponentEstimates() {
        return solutionComponentEstimates;
    }

    public void setSolutionComponentEstimates(List<SolutionComponentEstimate> solutionComponentEstimates) {
        this.solutionComponentEstimates = solutionComponentEstimates;
    }

    public List<BusinessEvent> getBusinessEvents() {
        return businessEvents;
    }

    public void setBusinessEvents(List<BusinessEvent> businessEvents) {
        this.businessEvents = businessEvents;
    }

    public Double getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(Double duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public List<SCVersionProject> getScvproject() {
        return scvproject;
    }

    public void setScvproject(List<SCVersionProject> scvproject) {
        this.scvproject = scvproject;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getDependencyProjectId() {
        return dependencyProjectId;
    }

    public void setDependencyProjectId(int dependencyProjectId) {
        this.dependencyProjectId = dependencyProjectId;
    }

    public boolean isDependencyStart() {
        return dependencyStart;
    }

    public void setDependencyStart(boolean dependencyStart) {
        this.dependencyStart = dependencyStart;
    }

    public int getDependencyDelta() {
        return dependencyDelta;
    }

    public void setDependencyDelta(int dependencyDelta) {
        this.dependencyDelta = dependencyDelta;
    }

    public Roadmap getRoadmap() {
        return roadmap;
    }

    public void setRoadmap(Roadmap roadmap) {
        this.roadmap = roadmap;
    }

}
```

I am new to JPA. Is there anything I am missing or any workaround for this? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: as you note, a direct insert works - so a null is permitted. This means that JPA must not be passing a null or the FK wouldn't be violated thus raising the error from the database. So I would question if JPA is making your null something else that then violates the constraint? (eg: If it is a number column, making it a zero or - if it is a string trying to insert a space). Can you dump out the values before insert? Or is there another FK on that table that you are violating with your test data?

Comment: turn on tracing and show that actual sql statements and bind variables used.

Comment: I am getting the same error not only for null value, but also for any value which is not there in the id column. For example, if I already have a row in the table with id 1000, and I am trying to insert a new row with dependency_project_id 2000, I get the same error. However, if I pass 1000 in the dependency_project_id, then it works fine.

Comment: Could you paste your Entity? It's hard to say without the mapping information

Comment: @areus I have uploaded my entity

Answer (score 0):

You should map DEPENDENCY_PROJECT_ID to an Integer instead of an int.
int can't have a null value. If is no set, the value is 0, and hence the constraint violation.

Comment: i tried but still not able to make it work. As mentioned, i am getting this error not only for null, but also for any value which is not there in the id column. For example, if I already have a row in the table with id 1000, and I am trying to insert a new row with dependency_project_id 2000, I get the same error. However, if I pass 1000 in the dependency_project_id, then it works fine

Comment: Of course it will fail for any value that is not already on the id column (except for null). That's the purpose of a foreign key constraint, it must reference a value that exists

Comment: So, I cannot make the dependency_project_id as foreign key in this case? Since my requirement is that, in certain cases, the dependency_project_id can be null however, the id value can never be null. Also, i am wondering how am i able to insert null directly in the DB even though there is not null value in the id field?

Comment: I changed the type from int to integer, even then I am not able to insert null from my service into the DB for the dependency_project_id field